# C program error: warning: implicit declaration of function 'itoa'

Tags: c

Why am I getting the `warning: implicit declaration of function 'itoa'` error? I've checked the header files and code. stdlib.h already added in directives. I'm totally lost as to why the warning/error keeps occurring.

I need to change a given CHAR date of format MM/YY to a NUMBER of YYYYMMDD. I used a function that takes the MM/YY variable as a parameter and breaks it down into separate variables, then concatenates them into a single variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int getNumDate (char *date);
    

int main()
{
    char prodDate[5 + 1];
    strcpy(prodDate,"03/12");
    
    printf("%d", getNumDate(prodDate));
    
    return 0;
}


int getNumDate (char *date)
{
  static char orig_mmyy[5 + 1];
  static char *str_ptr;
  static char *c_yy = NULL;
  static char *c_mm = NULL;
  static char *c_dd = NULL;
  char new_yy[4 + 1];
  char new_mm[2 + 1];
  char new_dd[2 + 1];
  strcpy(new_dd, "01");
  char finalDate_chars[8 + 1];
  int finalDate;
 
  strcpy(orig_mmyy, date);//store original MM/YY
  str_ptr = orig_mmyy;//copy MM/YY to str_ptr
  c_mm = strtok(str_ptr, "/");//store MM
  c_yy = strtok(NULL, "/");//store YY
  c_dd = "01";//set DD
  if( atoi(c_yy) < 65 )//1965 is the Go Date -- less than 65 must be 21st Century
  { 
      //****ERROR OCCURS HERE****//
      itoa(atoi(c_yy) + 2000, new_yy, 10);//convert YY to YYYY and copy to new YYYY
  }
  else
  {
     itoa(atoi(c_yy) + 1900, new_yy, 10);//convert YY to YYYY for 20th Century (1900s)
  }
  memcpy(new_mm, c_mm, sizeof(new_mm));//copy new MM
  memcpy(new_dd, c_dd, sizeof(new_dd));//copy new DD
  
  strcat(finalDate_chars,new_yy);
  strcat(finalDate_chars,new_mm);
  strcat(finalDate_chars,new_dd);
  finalDate = atoi(finalDate_chars);
  
  return finalDate;
}
```

Comment: `itoa()` isn't a standard C function, so may not be in your implmentation's library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `itoa` function in standard C.  You can use `snprintf` instead.

Also, `atoi` is available in standard C, but not a good idea to use because it has no way to reliably detect errors.  `strtol` is recommended instead.

Comment: How can snprintf convert the number back to a string?

Comment: @JaguarNation: These functions are well documented and you can find examples all over the Internet.  (For `snprintf` you may find more examples with `sprintf`, which is similar but less safe because it makes it harder to avoid buffer overflows; these examples would be easy to adapt.)  If you encounter specific questions when reading the documentation or examples, please search here to see if they are answered, and if not, ask as a new question (not as comments on this post).

Comment: Good points about the what's included in Standard C. I think sscanf is good for converting strings to int, and sprintf will work for converting int to string. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `sscanf` can also be used in place of `strtol`.  If you use `sprintf` instead of `snprintf` then you must be very careful to ensure your buffer is large enough for the longest possible output, and it can be hard to determine just how long that might be.  That's why I don't recommend it.

Comment: @JaguarNation: The one problem with `sscanf` is that if the string contains digits that form a valid number, but that number is too large for `int` (or whatever other type you have specified), then the C standard says the behavior is undefined, which would be very bad.  Most real implementations will behave sensibly in such a case, but it makes proper error handling more difficult.

Comment: Size won't matter in this particular scenario as the largest possibility (which will NEVER occur - lol) is 99991201. Thanks.